# Xcode warning order by occurance

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 3, the "Build Results" were by occurrence in the C/C++ compilation unit. As I switch to Xcode 12, I see the "building issues" has been arranged "View by File" or "View by Type." Sometimes, the order of the errors makes a lot of difference. Is there anything that will prevent re-ordering of errors by issue or by file and just output them by occurrence in the compiler?